# Plot color of values based on where they fall on a 1:1 line - R

Tags: r, graphics, plot

How would one set the color of data points depending if they above or below a 1:1 line?

It's very simple to do this for a vertical or horizontal line (abline), but how would one do this for a 1:1 line?

Here is how to do it for a horizontal line:

```
x <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
y <- c(2,4.9,5,9,12)
df <- cbind(x,y)

plot(df[,1], df[,2], xlim=c(0,15), ylim=c(0,15), pch = 21,
     bg =ifelse(df[,2]<=5,"black","red"), col = "black",  cex = 1.5, 
     cex.axis = 1.4, cex.lab = 1.4, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
abline(h=c(5.0),lty=2)
```

How would one do this for a 1:1 line where:

```
abline(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just test for `x > y` or equivalently `y <= x`:

```
plot(df[,1], df[,2], xlim=c(0,15), ylim=c(0,15), pch = 21,
     bg =ifelse(df[,2] <= df[,1],"black","red"), col = "black",  cex = 1.5, 
     cex.axis = 1.4, cex.lab = 1.4, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
abline(0, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh geez. Pretty simple. Thank you so much @BondedDust!

Comment: Hat tip to @jeremycg: I thought that `+(y < x)` had a certain elegance. That was my upvote on your currently deleted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution below will plot point colors according to how far they are from the abline.Simply calculate the deviation from the abline, then convert it to a color gradient and use it in the col argument in plot:

```
x <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
y <- c(2,4.9,5,9,12)
deviation <- abs(y-x)
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('blue','red'))
data_col=rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(deviation,breaks = 10))]
df <- cbind(x,y,deviation)
plot(x, y, xlim=c(0,15), ylim=c(0,15), pch = 21, col=data_col, bg=data_col)
abline(0, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is coloring points based on how far they are from the line, rather than whether they are above or below the line, no?  Either way, using `bg=data_col` might look nice!

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the recommendation. Done!